# Приложение крашится при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: java, android

Написал приложение, которое выводит информацию о операторе телефона, типе сети и т.д. После нажатия кнопки, оно вылетает. Ниже Код программы и логи.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView tv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.info);
    }

    public void onSubmit(View v) {
        TelephonyManager tm=(TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELECOM_SERVICE);
        int callstate=tm.getCallState();
        String callstat="";
        switch(callstate){
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                callstat="Call State: Phone is idle\n";
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                callstat="Call State: Phone is in use\n";
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                callstat="Call State: Phone is ringing\n";
                break;
        }
        String opname="\n Operator ID:"+""+tm.getNetworkOperator();
        opname=opname+"\n Operator Name:"+""+tm.getNetworkOperatorName();
        int phoneType=tm.getPhoneType();
        String ptype="";
        switch (phoneType){
            case TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_CDMA:
                ptype="\nPhone Type: CDMA";
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_GSM:
                ptype="\nPhone Type: GSM";
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_SIP:
                ptype="\nPhone Type: SIP";
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_NONE:
                ptype="\nPhone Type: NONE";
                break;
        }
        boolean isRoaming=tm.isNetworkRoaming();
        String pDetails="";
        if (isRoaming){
            pDetails="Roaming : Yes\n";
        }
        else {
            pDetails="Roaming : No\n";
        }
        tv.setText(callstat+opname+ptype+pDetails);
    }
}
```

LogCat:

> 11-12 14:44:42.527 25260-25260/com.galaxy.operator E/AndroidRuntime:
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                        Process: com.galaxy.operator, PID: 25260
>                                                                        java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for
>   android:onClick
>                                                                            at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
>                                                                            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5207)
>                                                                            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21177)
>                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:742)
>                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5527)
>                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                            at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
>                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629)
>                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                            at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
>                                                                            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5207) 
>                                                                            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21177) 
>                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:742) 
>                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
>                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5527) 
>                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                            at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739) 
>                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629) 
>                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   android.telecom.TelecomManager cannot be cast to
>   android.telephony.TelephonyManager
>                                                                            at com.galaxy.operator.MainActivity.onSubmit(MainActivity.java:26)
>                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                            at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
>                                                                            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5207) 
>                                                                            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21177) 
>                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:742) 
>                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
>                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5527) 
>                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                            at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739) 
>                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629)  11-12
>   14:44:42.531 25260-25260/com.galaxy.operator
>   E/MQSEventManagerDelegate: failed to get MQSService. 11-12
>   14:44:42.547 25260-25260/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 25260 SIG:
>   9

В манифесте дал такие разрешения:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Замените это

```
TelephonyManager tm= (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELECOM_SERVICE);
```

на это:

```
TelephonyManager tm=(TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
```

Comment: Благодарю, то что надо.